# View file info from a folder into DataGrid

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I want to view file info from a folder into datagrid.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<TabItem Header="Happy" Width="60" Height="30">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <DataGrid x:Name="MusicTabHappy" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="10">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="File Name"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Format"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Size"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

MainWindow.xaml.vb:

```
Public Class MusicLibrary
    Private Sub MusicTabHappy_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles MusicTabHappy.SelectionChanged
    (###)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function GetFileName(path As String) As String
        Dim filename As String = "C:\User\Desktop\A"
        result = path.GetFileName(filename)
        (###)
    End Function
End Class
```

Please help me, thank you so much.

Comment: I think we are missing something here. Files don't have a FirstName, or LastName. What are you binding to? What does your Function return? I am sorry but I am afraid this question needs a great deal of work.

Comment: @Mary oups sorry, there is a mistake that I have edited, ty for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `Directory.GetFiles` and `FileInfo` APIs to get information about the files. The below sample sets the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid` to an `IEnumerable(Of FileInfo)`:

```
MusicTabHappy.ItemsSource = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Temp").Select(Function(fileName)
                                                                               Return New FileInfo(fileName)
                                                                           End Function).ToArray()
```

You would then bind to the properties of the `FileInfo` in your XAML markup:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MusicTabHappy" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="10">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="File Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" Binding="{Binding LastAccessTime}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Format" Binding="{Binding Extension}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Size" Binding="{Binding Length}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="*" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Sry late for reply, I tested ur code is good, but I stuck to convert the size to bytes. I was added covert code on above, that's missing somethings in there.

Comment: @QiXuan: That's a different issue that has nothing to do with your original question really. Please ask a new question if you have another issue.